# Issue with return value after query in Sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, sqlite, return-value

In my app I am executing a query to get the count of images which are having same category and that category is passed by me as the parameter. Now when the query is executed I want to get two results either 1 or more than one. For that purpose I think I need to convert the string to integer. When I check the value of the String it is showing me 1 but when that value is returned to the method it is showing something like this:695842 and something else also. What could be the reason? Please help. I am posting the part of code:-

```
-(NSInteger)searchImagesInSameCategory:(NSString *)categoryName
{

    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory= [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *path=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SymbolTalkLanguageElement.sqlite"];


    //Open the database
    //might have to make database as property
    if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &dataBase) ==SQLITE_OK)
    {



        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        NSString *strSQL = [[NSString alloc]init];


        strSQL = @"select Count(ImageName) from tblLanguageElement where Category='";

        strSQL = [[strSQL stringByAppendingString:categoryName] stringByAppendingString:@"'"];


        const char *bar = [strSQL UTF8String]; 


        if(sqlite3_prepare(dataBase, bar, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {

                NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]);

                int k;

                //NSString *string=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

                //NSLog(string);

                k=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

                //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Count for k:-%d",k]);

                //[list addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];

                //return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

                return k;
            }

        }



    }
    return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `intValue` method to convert a `NSString` to `int`.

```
NSString *integerStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
k = [integerStr intValue];
```

Comment: @Christina, Always Welcome. Stack Overflow takes pleasure to help every one :-)